# Substituting the power of Exp by another variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I was trying to substitute the exponential term of

```
Exp[-(((mb + mc) (mc^2 (1 - x) + mb^2 x))/(8 mb mc (1 - x) x a))]
```

i.e., the term,

```
(((mb + mc) (mc^2 (1 - x) + mb^2 x))/(8 mb mc (1 - x) x a))
```

by a variable y, such that the output is Exp[-y].

But my concern is on performing replace all,

```
Exp[-(((mb + mc) (mc^2 (1 - x) + mb^2 x))/(8 mb mc (1 - x) x a)] /. {((mb + mc) (mc^2 (1 - x) + 
  mb^2 x))/(8 mb mc (1 - x) x a) -> y}
```

the replacement just does not happen, and I am returned the original exponent term.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried my code with the answer suggested in the answer section. It seemes to work but my concern is why does the substitution not work if we perform it in the way I tried in the original question?

Comment: If there is only one `Exp`, use `expr /. Exp[_] :> Exp[-y]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for the right syntax of the `ReplaceAll` rules.

```
Exp[-(((mb + mc) (mc^2 (1 - x) + mb^2 x))/(8 mb mc (1 - x) x a))] /. 
-(((mb + mc) (mc^2 (1 - x) + mb^2 x))/(8 mb mc (1 - x) x a)) -> y
```

It gives:

> e^y

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked for me.